# Different Views for connected Users in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, associations

I got 3 controller/tables *Users* / *Adresses* / *AdressesUsers*

This is my Adresses View function

```
/**
 * View method
 *
 * @param string|null $id Adress id.
 * @return \Cake\Network\Response|null
 * @throws \Cake\Datasource\Exception\RecordNotFoundException When record not found.
 */
public function view($id = null)
{
    $this->viewBuilder()->layout('user');
    $uid = $this->request->session()->read('Auth.User.id');

    $adress = $this->Adresses->get($id, [
        'contain' => ['Users']
    ]);

    $counter = 0;
    foreach($adress['users'] as $userid){
        $users[$counter] = $userid['id'];
    }

    if(in_array($uid, $users)) {
        $adress['dabei'] = 1;
    } else {
        $adress['dabei'] = 0;            
    } 

    $this->set('adress', $adress);
    $this->set('_serialize', ['adress']);
}
```

I want all the users who are connected with the adress to see more detail information. How do I reach that goal? Tried to do it with a if clause, but didn´t work, since I get an array of more then just one user (since multiple users can connect to one adress (adress of orders - not their own).

**EDIT**: I used an foreach loop to find out which users are in it and use an if/else in my view. But I think this is not best practice :/

Comment: `$counter` is not being incremented... while that code surely could be improved/simplified (`!empty(collection($adress->users)->firstMatch(['id' => $uid]))`), the actual problem with it merely seems to be more than a typo...

Comment: @ndm yes I added !empty and the increment already. What I don´t get is the ->firstMatch

Seems to work. So I guess there is no function for that in Cake. Thanks again for your help. Hope I can help people some day too ^^

Comment: It looks like you database structure is not perfect. Users can have more than one address, so you basically should start with the users table, containing adresses. Than just load the user containing addresses. If the result set has one or more adress you can alter your output (in the view).

Comment: It´s on purpose that they can have multiple adresses - since these are connected with orders. The real adresses of the users are in the table users.

The above seems to work for me.